# Читаю книгу по тематике операционных систем. Помогите понять, что подразумевалось под приведенной мной цитатой?

Tags: книги, ос, пк

> Программы, с которыми взаимодействуют пользователи, обычно называемые оболочкой, когда они основаны на применении текста, и графическим пользовательским интерфейсом (Graphical User Interface (GUI)), когда в них используются значки, фактически не являются частью операционной системы, хотя задействуют эту систему в своей работе.

Что значит "программы, основаные на применении текста"? Тип там текст печатают, что-ли? То же самое про значки. Что под ними подразумевается?
Является ли приведенная мной цитата из книги правдивой? Просто, как я понял, если это программы, используемые пользователями, то почему они не являются частью ОС (ведь я же там могу использовать майкрософт калькулятор или играть в пасьянс)? В чем тогда "подвох" и разница, когда они либо "являются частью ОС", или, как тут написано, "задействуют ее в своей работе"?

Comment: Программы можно удалить - ОС при этом продолжит работать. Значит, они не часть ОС.

Comment: *`"Что значит "программы, основаные на применении текста"? "`* -- например, shell в \*nix, cmd.exe в винде. Вы печатаете текст команд и читаете их текстовый вывод в терминале. / А текст *"хотя задействуют эту систему в своей работе"* в самом деле странный, поскольку все программы, исполняемые в ОС, используют ее в той или иной мере. / Ну, для более предметного обсуждения, вы могли бы написать, что именнно вы сами считаете ОС.

Comment: Эта цитата - не про пасьянс или калькулятор. Она про оболочки операционной системы. Это шелл (/bin/sh в юниксах, cmd.exe в виндовзах; "shell", кстати, и значит "оболочка") в случае с "применением текста" и привычный графический интерфейс винды в случае с "графическим пользовательским интерфейсом".

Answer (score 0):

Просто вы видимо не застали оболочки вроде Norton Commander, Volkov Commander... Впрочем, и сейчас есть такой FAR Manager. Они текстовые по интерфейсу (вернее псевдографические), но очень облегчали работу с файлами в MS DOS, да и в Windows тоже. Это внешние программы, они не входят в ОС.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]